# Puppet Code coverage testing using rspec

Tags: ruby, code-coverage, rspec-puppet

My Module structure is this.

```
install_logging
├── files
│   └── install_logging.sh
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── manifests
│   ├── \
│   ├── empty.rb
│   └── init.pp
├── Modulefile
├── Rakefile
├── README
├── spec
│   ├── chkcls_sec.rb
│   ├── classes
│   │   ├── init1_spec.rb
│   │   ├── init_spec.rb
│   │   └── spec_helper.rb
│   ├── coverage_spec.rb
│   ├── defines
│   ├── fixtures
│   │   ├── manifests
│   │   │   └── site.pp
│   │   └── modules
│   │       └── install_logging
│   │           ├── files -> ../../../../files
│   │           ├── manifests -> ../../../../manifests
│   │           └── templates -> ../../../../templates
│   ├── functions
│   ├── hosts
│   └── spec_helper.rb
├── templates
│   └── agent.sh.erb
└── tests
    └── init.pp
```

manifests/init.pp file code.

```
class install_logging {
  file { '/tmp/install_logging.sh':
    ensure => 'present',
    mode   => '0644',
    source => 'puppet:///modules/install_logging/install_logging.sh'
  }-> exec { 'Install Logging Agent':
    provider  => shell,
    command   => 'bash /tmp/install_logging.sh',
    logoutput => on_failure,
  }
}

$ua_module_name = 'VivekMishra01/Google_Cloud_Logging1'  
$ua_module_version = "${ua_module_name}/1.1.0" 

file { '/tmp/agent.sh':
  ensure  => file,
  mode    => '0755',
  content => template('gcloudsdk/agent.sh.erb'),
  require => Exec['Remove Components'],
}-> exec { 'Agent':
  provider  => shell,
  command   => 'sh /tmp/agent.sh',
  logoutput => on_failure,
}
```

spec/classes/init_spec.rb file code

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'contains install_logging' do
  it { File.exist?('File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),init.pp)') }
end
at_exit { RSpec::Puppet::Coverage.report! }
```

This is what I am trying to do.

```
root@ubuntu-14-04:/home/vivekkumarmishra17/Mymodule/install_logging# rspec spec/classes/init_spec.rb 
.
Finished in 0.00164 seconds (files took 0.59198 seconds to load)

    1 example, 0 failures
    Total resources:   0
    Touched resources: 0
    Resource coverage:   NaN%
    Untouched resources:
```

Problem is that why it's not able to find any resource although 1 example is tested successfully.

```
    Total resources:   0
    Touched resources: 0
    Resource coverage:   NaN%
    Untouched resources:
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review your question and fix the formatting so it's more readable. You have commentary in your code, and unformatted command-line output; The effort you put into making your question readable pays off. Also, giving us the necessary information helps us help you. Read "[ask]" including the links, and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 0):

Please use the [Puppet Development Kit](https://puppet.com/blog/develop-modules-faster-new-puppet-development-kit) to generate your modules and classes. The PDK will generate working unit tests for those.

For writing unit tests using rspec-puppet, please refer to the [docsite](http://rspec-puppet.com/), in this case, specifically to [testing classes](http://rspec-puppet.com/documentation/classes/#basic-test-structure), and [resources](http://rspec-puppet.com/documentation/classes/#test-a-resource).